# Finding a mid-angle line between many points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, triangles

For any 3 non-colinear points in 3d space (A, B, and Z) there should exist a line/vector M that connects Z to AB where AZM = MZB.
[image: image1]

I am trying to find a corresponding M for a model with 5 points where none of the points are necessarily coplanar.
[image: image2]

What would M be here? Does M have to exist? Under what circumstances would it exist?

Comment: Maybe you can try with 4 points $A,B,C,Z$ first. Is there some point $M$ that makes $\angle AZM = \angle BZM = \angle CZM$?

Comment: yes, when A,B,C form an equilateral triangle and Z is orthogonal to that triangle, M would be the midpoint of that triangle. But I cant assume Z is orthogonal, or that the triangle is equilateral